# How can i access location data like latitude and longitude from android location service?

Tags: android, service, gps, location

I have the following location service:

GPSService.java:

```
public class GPSService extends SensorElement {

    private static final String TAG = "GPSServive";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                    LOCATION_DISTANCE, mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i in an android activity get access to Location latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used google play services location client.

It is the most up to date and accurate location fusing both wi-fi and gps.

The downsize is that i need google play services to run it but the older versions are no longer bug free sometimes just starting to provide empty location and a smartphone reboot is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Its in the Location object, see [Location docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html). You can do it like that:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
      mLastLocation.set(location);
      double latitude = location.getLatitude();
      double longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: But does that mean that the activity has to implement LocationListener? Or you are saying that i put that inside the Service  and create methods to access it and then call them in the activity?

Comment: Having it in your activity would also be a solution. It depends on what you want to achieve. Google Maps for example removes GPS updates in onPause() of the Activity, in such case - your activity can control the listener with it's lifecycle. When you still want to have it in your service, you can use a binder (onBind) and send position data to your activity from the service.

Comment: Can you provide a specific implementation of an android activity with the binder?